# How do I set the static library path in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, macports

Instead of typing :

```
g++ functions.cpp  /opt/local/lib/libhdf5.a /opt/local/lib/libsiloh5.a  /opt/local/lib/libz.a
```

I would prefer to type:

```
g++ functions.cpp  -lhdf5 -lsiloh5 -lz
```

I think that I need to add /opt/local/lib (Macports lib install location) to my library path. I have tried:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATHS="/opt/local/lib"
```

None work

Answer (score 3):

The normal command line is to use the -L option to add the path to the library search

```
g++ functions.cpp -L/opt/local/lib -lhdf5 -lsiloh5 -lz
```

Comment: +1. Here's some additional information.
There are built-in directories that g++ will search for libraries. Run `g++ --print-search-dirs` to see these. Unless you got g++ from macports (highly unlikely), it won't search /opt/local/lib by default.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X the environment variable:

```
$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Is the one that you want.

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib"
```

does the trick, allowing you to conveniently link to macports static libraries.

Remember to restart your shell.

Comment: DYLD is for dynamic libraries when the app runs ie .dylib (or .so) and not static linking which is at link time

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do

```
export LDFLAGS='-L/opt/local/lib'
```